# Redirect output of each process to QtabWidget tabs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt5, queue, output

**any one can help to fix this script
I want separate each process output into tab1 and tab2.**

tab1 output be like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OSqG.png)

tab2 output be like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQbMV.png)

is there any way to separate process output

"""

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import multiprocessing as mp
import datetime
import time
```

"I create 2 function each one generate date and numbers "

```
def producer(q):
    proc = mp.current_process()
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        data = str(now)
        q.put(data)
        time.sleep(1)

def counting(q):
                                     
    proc = mp.current_process() 
    count = 1
    while True:
        q.put(str(count))
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1

class Consumer(QThread):
    poped = pyqtSignal(str)

   def __init__(self, q):
    super().__init__()
    self.q = q

def run(self):
    while True:
        if not self.q.empty():
            data = q.get()
            self.poped.emit(data)
```

"tabs are here "

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, q):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 200)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(300, 200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3, "Tab3")

        # Create first tab
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tab2.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.text = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)        
        self.text2 = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)        
        self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.text2)
        self.tab2.setLayout(self.tab2.layout)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

    
        # thread for data consumer
        self.consumer = Consumer(q)
        self.consumer.poped.connect(self.print_data)
        self.consumer.start()


    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def print_data(self, data):
        self.statusBar().showMessage(data)
        self.text.appendPlainText(data)
        self.text2.appendPlainText(data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()

    # producer process
    p = Process(name="producer", target=producer, args=(q, ), daemon=True)
    p.start()
    p2 = Process(name="producer", target=counting, args=(q, ), daemon=True)
    p2.start()
    # Main process
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = MyWindow(q)
    mywindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways You can achieve what You want.
This solution uses header as a data identifier.
Then You can interpret Your data as You need based on its header.

Here is Your modified code:

```
import datetime
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def producer(q, header):
    while True:
        data = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        q.put((header, data))
        time.sleep(1)


def counting(q, header):
    count = 1
    while True:
        data = str(count)
        q.put((header, data))
        time.sleep(1)
        count += 1


class Consumer(QThread):
    poped = pyqtSignal(int, str)

    def __init__(self, q):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = q

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not self.q.empty():
                self.poped.emit(*q.get())


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, q):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 200)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(300, 200)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3, "Tab3")

        # Create first tab
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tab2.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.text = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)
        self.text2 = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)
        self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.text2)
        self.tab2.setLayout(self.tab2.layout)

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        # thread for data consumer
        self.consumer = Consumer(q)
        self.consumer.poped.connect(self.print_data)
        self.consumer.start()

    @pyqtSlot(int, str)
    def print_data(self, header, data):
        self.statusBar().showMessage(data)
        if header == 0:
            self.text.appendPlainText(data)
        elif header == 1:
            self.text2.appendPlainText(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()

    # Create producer with header=0
    p = Process(name="producer", target=producer, args=(q, 0), daemon=True)
    p.start()
    # Create producer with header=1
    p2 = Process(name="producer", target=counting, args=(q, 1), daemon=True)
    p2.start()
    # Main process
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywindow = MyWindow(q)
    mywindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```